# PyDev package build and compile from command line in linux

Tags: python, pydev

I have created a `PyDev` project in eclipse. I have added `PyDev` packages to the project. How can I build and compile `PyDev` package from command line. I am using `linux` virtual enviornment. The project structure is shown below.

e.g. I want to build and compile "bridge" package from command line. (reference project structure in image). This package do not have dependencies. So that it could be build and compiled individually.

[PyDev Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ZT8.png)

Comment: Python is a script language, so its code does not need to be built or compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really compile files for Python, just run them and their bytecode will be generated on demand and then used to run the code.

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for details on how to run your code inside PyDev.